# How to make md-chips md-separator-keys work along with md-autocomplete?

Tags: html, angular-material

When I use md-chips with md-separator-keys it works. 
If I add md-autocomplete then md-separator-keys DOESN'T work.

This how I use it:

```
<md-chips ng-model="chips.selectedChips" md-add-on-blur="true" md-separator-keys="customKeys"
          md-transform-chip="chips.transformChip($chip)"
          md-require-match="chips.allowToAddNew" md-autocomplete-snap>
  <md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="chips.selectedItem"  
      md-search-text="chips.searchText"
      md-items="item in chips.querySearch(chips.searchText)"
      md-item-text="chips.getText(item)"
      placeholder="{{ field.hint }}">
    <span md-highlight-text="chips.searchText">{{ chips.getText(item) }}</span>
  </md-autocomplete>
  <md-chip-template>
    <span>{{ chips.getText($chip) }}</span>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

customKeys are initialized like this:

```
scope.customKeys = [ $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ENTER, $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.COMMA, 186 ];
```

Question is:how to make it work?

p.s. for some reason add-on-blur doesn't work as well, also would be nice to find out how to fix it.

p.p.s. I've found CLOSED [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8479) on github, so they're not going to fix this valid issue. Fascinating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I know it's not a perfect solution but rather a workaround.
This what I've added to my custom directive's link method:

```
scope.$watch('chips.searchText', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!newValue || newValue.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
    if (";,".indexOf(newValue.substring(newValue.length - 1)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    var chipName = newValue.substring(0, newValue.length - 1);
    if (!scope.chips.selectedChips) {
        scope.chips.selectedChips = [];
    }
    scope.chips.selectedChips.push(scope.chips.transformChip(chipName));
    scope.chips.searchText = '';
});
```

And I removed `md-separator-keys` from `md-chips` since it became completely redundant